# Replacing weird chars in MySQL

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

Some of my texts are being displayed weird and I need to replace some chars on it. However I am having trouble with a specific char, the following one (javascript code, to show the difference between chars):

```
<script>
alert('–'.charCodeAt(0) + ':' + '-'.charCodeAt(0));
</script>
```

In MySQL I tried to apply the following query:

```
UPDATE translation SET columnx = REPLACE(columnx, '–', '-');
```

But it affects 0 rows. Therefore the question is, what is the right query to replace these weird chars to the correct one?

**UPDATE**

The weird char is displayed like this (the square):

[image: Weird char, displayed as square]

In the JSON, it is encoded as `\u0096` instead of  `-`

Comment: ... or you could fix the root problem and make your chars display "normal".

Comment: There is a mechanism that takes these text (all in ISO-8859-1), encodes them on UTF-8, generate JSONs from them, and display them on other side from the JSONs, where they appear like squares. I don't have control of this and have been asked to correct the database. I've suceeded on other chars like replacing `“` to `"` but no luck with this specific one.

Comment: Good luck then. You're basically stuck with 7 bit ASCII...

Comment: Can you show how exactly the characters show up weird? Fixing the root cause can be easy.

Comment: @Pekka I've updated the question with more information.

Comment: How are you fetching the data from the database and outputting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like not charset but collation related. A collation defines how MySQL treats chars "almost equal" when it comes to sorting or comparation.

For example the iso-8859-15 default collation will treat `ü = u`

What you can do is to treat your field like a bin collation.
A binary collation does not treat similar characters equal.

Select your correct binary collation

```
SELECT CHARACTER_SET_NAME, COLLATION_NAME FROM information_schema.COLLATIONS WHERE COLLATION_NAME LIKE '%bin%';
```

Then execute your update like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET columnx = REPLACE( columnx COLLATE latin1_bin, '–', '-' );
```

**CORRECTION:**
REPLACE compares are always done using a binary collation

**EDIT:**

If you still get 0 rows updated you probably don't replace the correct character.
Convert a string containing the character to hex and post the hex value so we can find out which char we are talking about

e.g.

```
SELECT HEX( columnx ) LIMIT 1;
```

**EDIT2:**

Just seen, you actually said you get `\u0096` which is a control character called [START OF GUARDED AREA](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/96/index.htm).. what ever program this character creates.. in hex this is `0xC2 0x96`.
In your example query you are replacing a characer called [EN DASH](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm)

It's hard to replace a control character by just pasting it, conversions might break it up. Instead you can use [UNHEX( hexval )](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex) to tell MySQL which character you mean

```
UPDATE TABLE SET columnx = REPLACE( columnx UNHEX( 'C296' ), '-' );
```

or to make this more clear (or even more confusing :)), this passes the "normal" hypen as hex value as well

```
UPDATE TABLE SET columnx = REPLACE( columnx UNHEX( 'C296' ), UNHEX( '2D' ) );
```

Answer (score 3):

Like Alvaro said, you should really try to change your database to the correct character set. Usually the utf-8 character set should be enough.

For further information look here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html

If you have no rights to do so maybe take a look at:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/charset-convert.html
and
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9944/mysql-transfer-iso-8859-1-to-utf-8

Comment: That would involve changing all they systems who access the database, I don't think it is viable in our context.